# App crashes when i apply crashlytics on it

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

App crashes when i apply `crashlytics` on it

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.ehs.pk, PID: 20963
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ehs.pk-8.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ehs.pk-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4993)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4585)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4499)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ehs.pk-8.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ehs.pk-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4978)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4585) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4499) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Add more information, such as code, or how you included Crashlytics. Post for example your build.gradle file.

Comment: try to clean and rebuilt your code!

Comment: you could have just hit the 64k limit "multidex"

Comment: @Blundell why you say it (64k limit)?

Comment: here the [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) to what @Blundell suggested ;)

Comment: Thanks @PeppermintPaddy for the link! but I also wanted to know how Blundell did he understand that the problem was that?

Comment: @PaoloMastrangelo I think because of this `Didn't find class ... on path: DexPathList` and this `dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)` line

Comment: @PeppermintPaddy ok thanks :)

Comment: exactly, sorry I was in a rush before

Comment: Thank you it works.

Comment: @PeppermintPaddy Can you submit this as an answers so I can upvote :) Thansk from the Crashlytics team!

Comment: @ToddBurner done ;)

Comment: What step solved it? Can the OP please post the solution? I'm having the same issue and none of this seemed to work.

Comment: I see this but only when I build via Android Studio. If I use command line Gradle then everything is fine.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, is related to the 64k limit "multidex".

I was using `multiDexEnabled true` property in build.gradle in `defaultConfig` block, under `android` one.

As stated in [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

for devices with **Android API prior to 21**, we need to include the multidex library (`implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'`)

and extend `MultiDexApplication` in our Application class

Comment: If anyone facing this issue on API level **above 21**, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/52813496/5460053. As I faced this issue on **API 27 Android Pie**

Answer (score 10):

I have solved this problem by doing the following:

In the Application class:

```
@Override
public void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    try {
        MultiDex.install(this);
    } catch (RuntimeException multiDexException) {
        multiDexException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

We were having the same issue, and disabling instant run in Android Studio seemed to get it working.

On mac
Android Studio Settings or Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run.

Answer (score 7):

By looking at this part...

`Didn't find class ... on path: DexPathList ...` `dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoade‌​r.java:67)`

of the stack trace you can figure out that your test device is probably pre-Lollipop (Android 5.0) and that you just hit the 64k limit. You can fix it as described [here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: I am having such issue with Android API 26 and above, Android Studio 3.1

Comment: @neobie I got the same when I updated, using multidex doesn't seem to help. Did you solve it?

Comment: @fuskaren what is your min API level?

Comment: @PeppermintPaddyIts It's 15 but it crashes on any version directly on start.

Comment: Or actually it might just crash on versions over 25.

Comment: did you do all 3 steps described in the link I posted? first insert gradle dependency, then `multiDexEnabled true` and then `MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication` or add `MultiDexApplication` to manifest?

Comment: @PeppermintPaddy Yeah, I did all those things. The crashes started after I updated android studio to 3.1. Before that it was all working fine without multidex.

Comment: @fuskaren I am adding more proguard rules for those library causing error.. not sure why it only happens after Android Studio 3.1

Comment: @neobie I'll try that. Are you also using multidex or is that not the issue? Mind showing what rules you added?

Comment: @neobie Did you solve it? I'm still not getting it to work.

Comment: This is not a dex limit problem. If you hit the 65k limit you'd know it at compile time. You'd never even make it to runtime to see the crash OP shared. It *may* be a multidex problem (i.e. you already setup multidex and this class isn't being loaded as part of first dex file)

Answer (score 7):

This could be an issue with Instant Run. Turn off the Instant Run and run the build again. I faced the same issue and it resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

When minifyEnabled is true while using firebase or crashlytics this problem may happens. Enabling minifyEnabled shrinks methods and classes names to lowest possible characters (changing names and that raises ClassNotFoundException). Unfortunately, firebase and crashlytics versions had many problem with that. To solve it just tell proguard to not shrink those classes by writing the next lines in proguard file "proguard-rules.pro" as:

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.*.* { *; }
```

Now if the problem not go away or it didn't find other classes like yours, then check your base project build.gradle dependencies version of gradle and others. I found these version is free of that error:

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'

}
```

Remeber you can put any classes path into that proguard file so it did not change its name or methods when minify is enabled, and that will help you with other classes "ClassNotFoundException" as well.

Also to test this in debugging, you can adjust debug setting in build.gradle as:

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
```

Comment: These are overly broad proguard rules. I don't think you need to keep *all* of Crashlytics and *all* of Firebase to solve the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just one more case:

In my case, I disabled instant run, added `multiDexEnabled true` in my gradle, and added the `'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` to my dependencies, called the `MultiDex.install(this);` directly in my custom application, but I still got the same error. The error only occurs in the system Android 4.4. Everything works well on Android 7.0 and 9.0.

Finally, moving the `MultiDex.install(this);` from the `onCreate(Context)` method to the `attachBaseContext(Context)` solved my problem.

So, you should call `MultiDex.install(this);` in `attachBaseContext(Context)` instead of `onCreate(Context)` when you don't plan to extend the `MultiDexApplication` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens when you run with `minifyEnabled true`, add this rule in your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keep public class com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider
```