# Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

After `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'` and `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

I started getting the following error when starting the application:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.fentury.android, PID: 10771
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
>                     install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5856)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                      Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
>                     install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
>                         at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:235)
>                         at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:209)
>                         at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
>                         at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
>                         at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
>                         at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
>                         at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:440)
>                         at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:384)
>                         at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:342)
>                         at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:313)
>                         at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate(CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:27)
>                         at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
>                         at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
>                           ... 10 more

Also added in `AndroidManifest.xml` next line:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

Comment: As mentioned in the error message, the app uses Crashlytics. You might want to [set it up](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started)

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Doesn't help, same error :(

Comment: Have you added the crashlytics dependency to your build.gradle  @ Morozov?

Comment: @A.N.T yep, `implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
        transitive = true` and before the firebase implementation of all worked perfectly

Comment: Have you added fabric meta-data in your manifest @ Morozov ?

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284814/app-crashes-when-i-apply-crashlytics-on-it).

Comment: Did you try signing up on fabric and installing fabric plugin in android studio and login in that plugin?

Comment: For me the issue was that i was missing  - apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

Comment: if you are using Firebase crashlytics you have to enable it from the firebase console . I also faced the same error because of this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This helped to solve my problem

```
<meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
```

And remove this:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't this disable crash reporting?

Comment: @algrid nope. Try it.Then u can try to create an error artificially.

Comment: no help for me. Crashes number increased after I change crashlytics from version 2.9.4 to 2.9.5. Now I use 2.10.0 and ndk:2.1.0, many crashes still appears.

Answer (score 15):

I found that the only thing you need to do after following the instruction on the [Firebase Crashlytics docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started) is to apply the fabric plugin in your app build file (This step is actually missing from the docs!).

In your app-level build.gradle add the following

```
// Apply the Fabric plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Edit: It appears that this step has been recently added to the docs (See Step 2 / part 2).

Comment: This needs more emphasis. It is actually in the docs now (See Step 2 / part 2) yet I totally missed it until I saw this comment.

Comment: @ralfoide You are correct it needs more emphasis indeed. I believe this was recently added to the docs as it was not there when I last checked.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use other Firebase's API's, I'd suggest to setup **crashlytics**
As mentioned on Firebase's crashlytics page, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started).

And obviously before that you'd need to setup firebase for your app
and create project through firebase console.
I believe you had already done that.

It's because I see small difference in crashlytics setup on these two pages(fabric and firebase).
like on firebase's crashlytics:
in app level gradle

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
}
```

on fabric:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
      implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
}
```

You won't need to add fabric api key through manifest if you are using with firebase, I think it somehow get connected with firebase key(just guessing).
I'm saying this from my experience, anyone correct me if I'm somewhere wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well it was caused by using the incorrect `Fabric.with()` initializer for debug builds.

**Don’t use:**

```
// Set up Crashlytics, disabled for debug builds
Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
        .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
                .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .build())
        .build();

// Initialize Fabric with the debug-disabled Crashlytics
Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit, new Crashlytics()); // WRONG!
```

**Instead use:**

```
// Set up Crashlytics, disabled for debug builds
Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
        .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
                .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .build())
        .build();

// Initialize Fabric with the debug-disabled Crashlytics
Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit); // Correct initializer!
```

Documentation: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#disable-crashlytics-for-debug-builds

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was building app for android 4.4 compatibility which does not have build in Multidex support. I solved the problem by following steps bellow to enable Multidex for android 4.4 and the problem went away:
[Enable multidex for apps with over 64K methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.)

David